# SSL error when installing Python module

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

When i try to install a module (numpy, scipy .. etc) into Python 3.5.0, It gives the following error, for both `pip` and `easy_install`:

> error: [SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:1976)

How can I fix this?

Comment: It would probably be more appropriate to post this on `python-list` than Stackoverflow. Subscribe to `python-list` through the http://www.python.org/ site.